How to properly note a subset which contains overlapping sets
I try to describe the logic of some algorithms I perform on meshes (in finite element analysis).
suppose i have some elements called e within some domain $E_\Omega$, each being a set of nodes n. Those n can be mutually shared between several e.
Example:
$E_\Omega= \left\{ n_1 ,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5,n_6 \right\}$
$e_1=\left\{n_1,n_2\right\}$
$e_2=\left\{n_2,n_3\right\}$
$e_3=\left\{n_1,n_4\right\}$
$e_4=\left\{n_4,n_6\right\}$
$e_5=\left\{n_5,n_6\right\}$
For some $e_i$, I now try to find all other e that share a node (i.e. be neighbors) to create a set $E_{neb}$. In software this is rather simple, but how do I describe this mathematically correctly?
following above example, i may wish to find a set of all "neighbors" of $e_4$ which would be $E_{neb,e_4}=\left\{e_3,e_5\right\}$ in that case.
I was thinking something like this:
$E_{neb, e_i}= E_{\Omega} \cap e_i  \neq \emptyset$
update: something like this:
$E_{neb,e_i}= \left\{  e_j \subset E_{\Omega} \vert  e_j \cap e_i \neq \emptyset\right\}$
so, more specifically, I want the set of elements (which itself are sets of nodes), for which it is true that they share a node with $e_i$.
thanks for all input, really apprechiate your help.
\Update: example added in

Not sure this is clear.  I gather you have a big set, $E_{\Omega}$ and that you have a collection of subsets ${e_i}$ of that, right?  Now, you fix one of the subsets, $e_i$ and you want all the indices $j$ such that $e_i\cap e_j\neq \emptyset$. Is this right?  Assuming I have it write, I'd just let $S_i$ be the set of all those indices $j$.  It's important to make the dependence on $i$ clear.

Example (of my interpretation).  Let $E_{\Omega}$ be the set of natural numbers. Let $e_1={1,2,3}$, $e_2={4,5,6}$, $e_3={1, 10, 11, 12}$, $e_4={3, 4,5}$.  Then, using my notation, $S_1={1, 3,4}$.  In particular, $i$ is always in $S_i$ unless $e_i$ is empty.

thank you. $e_i$ is an arbitrary element within $E_\Omega$.  Think of it as acutal geometric elements that actually overlap at their nodes. I do not need indices of all overlapping elements but those that overlap just that one. However, I like your Idea of having a set of the indices, I'll think about it

Your post is hard to follow.  In particular, it's not at all clear what things are subsets and which are nodes.  I suggest:  Focus on clarity.  Efficiency of notation is a worthy goal ,but clarity is essential.

$E_{neb}= "all"  e_j \subset E_{\Omega} "where"  e_j \cap e_i \neq \emptyset$
but this written properly

Again, since your definition critically depends on the choice of $i$, whether $e_i$ is a subset or just a single node, your notation should involve $i$.

sorry, I don't get what you mean, which is why I cannot clarify.  $i$ is just some index describing which element has been chosen, it is arbitrary.

Again, your post is very vague so I'm trying to guess at what you mean.  I thought you fixed $e_i$, whether that's one node or a subset of nodes.  Then I thought you wanted to know all the subsets which overlapped with that specific choice $e_i$.  I suggest:  Edit your post to contain an explicit example of what you actually want.  Say $E_{\Omega}={n_1, n_2, n_3,n_4, n_5, n_6}$, so you have six nodes all in all.  Now pick your subsets however you like and write out what you mean.

thanks, updated accordingly

Well, that seems in line with my guess,  and therefore the thing you want depends on the choice of $i$

One distinction: you appear to reject the notion that $e_i$ intersects itself.  That's fine,  of course,  but if that's your rule you should state it.

I maybe understand now. Of course it is based upon i, I want to formally describe this process of getting $E_{nebs}$ for i. Also, the set is allowed to contain $e_i$ itself.

Well,  your example didn't include $e_4$.  Like I say,  clarity is critical. You can have whatever rules you want,  but they need to be clear.

corrected the question as suggested.
